# Codeigniter active record join function returns only one result

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a code, which must return joined data from two separate table.

```
$this->db->select('product.name,category.name');
$this->db->from('product');
$this->db->join('category','product.cat=category.id');
$this->db->group_by('product.name, category.name');
$query=$this->db->get();
```

but code returns only one column of data from product table.
I tried sql query too

```
select * from `product` join `category` where product.cat=category.id
```

In codeigniter it does not work, but in PhpMyAdmin and Sequel Pro sql terminals it works.
Can you help me please?

Comment: Have you tried echo $this->db->last_query(); to see what it's actually running and compare it to that which you're testing manually in PHPMyAdmin and Sequel Pro?

Comment: Yes, I tried this, it returns sql like this
    SELECT `product`.`name`, `category`.`name` FROM (`product`) RIGHT JOIN `category` ON `product`.`cat`=`category`.`id` ORDER BY `product`.`name`, `category`.`name`
and this query works in PHPMyAdmin

Comment: RIGHT join? I don't see RIGHT in your queries!

Comment: You don't specify the right join in your sample code above, nor the example you claim to have tried directly. Which is the one which produces the results you're looking for as they should produce different results?

Answer (score 1):

Your group by doesn't really make sense. Did you mean to use `order_by`?

`$this->db->order_by('product.name, category.name');`